# Sync bookmarks between iOS8 and OS X 10.10 without iCloud

Tags: macos, ios, data-synchronization, bookmarks

iCloud is not on option. Sync via Google solutions is not an option for the same reasons. Looking for a local sync solution.

How can I locally sync bookmarks between iOS 8 and OS X 10.10? I cannot believe this is not possible and Apple did indeed kill off this important functionality in regards to privacy with iTunes 11 and newer.

What options do I have? Jailbreak, iFile and manipulate the file where iOS stores it's bookmarks manually? Really?! Considering [Tim Cook held a strong speech](http://www.theguardian.com/technology/2015/feb/13/apple-ceo-tim-cook-challenges-obama-privacy) at the recent cybersecurity summit, it would be great to not only do the PR talking but also provide key functionality to restore privacy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question: no this is not possible. The non-free workaround is to buy the 40$ SyncMate from Eltima Software: http://www.sync-mac.com/

I'm not affiliated with that company. It's just all I found to solve this problem. If anybody has a better solution please post it.